# Why do programs seem to utilize cpu0 the most?

Tags: windows, cpu, intel, processor

For example, say I run a game that can only execute two threads at a time, one for audio, one for everything else. Looking at process explorer, it seems that 90% of the work is being done on CPU0. There is some activity on the other cores, but the majority happens on CPU0. I understand that the scheduler will run the next thread that needs time on the first available CPU, but why is cpu0 being utilized the most by this process?

[While game's running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KaE4.png) | [While it's not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHqgm.png)

Is it perhaps because for this particular processors design (i7 920 d0) it would be faster? (taking into account distance to cache, sharing, etc.)
Or something more basic, 0 comes before 1?

Sorry if this was asked before or if this question would be better suited for another community, but google and the SO search returned nothing relevant.

Comment: I know that some games that are not multi-threaded will configure themselves to have an affinity for exactly 1 CPU because their developers seem to think they get more stable timing that way... which is symptomatic of a timer that uses `RDTSC` instead of a proper monotonic clock.

Comment: I'm going to assume you mean parallelized (or something similar) instead of multithreaded, because I'm not sure there has been a game produced in the last 15 years that wasn't multithreaded. The example I refer to does support multiple cores as it always has two threads running, but I am not sure if the programmers are specifically limiting threads to one core each. Everything I've read about the topic says that's a bad idea unless you're making some highly specialized software for a particular set of hardware, but maybe.